# How to use datepicker javascript

Tags: javascript

I had visited this site:

http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker

I followed exactly (I guess) what he said on that site, but still not working.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker_jqui.css">        
<style type="text/css">     
input.date {
    width: 150px;
    color: #000;
}
</style>    
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<label>Datepicker with Vista skin:</label>
<input name='date_B' type='text' value='' class='date demo_vista' />

<label>Datepicker with OSX Dashboard skin:</label>
<input name='date_B' type='text' value='' class='date demo_dashboard' />

<label>Datepicker with jQuery UI skin:</label>
<input name='date_B' type='text' value='' class='date demo_jqui' />

<label>Datepicker basic (CSS only):</label>
<input name='date_B' type='text' value='' class='date demo' />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    new DatePicker('.demo_vista', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_vista' });
    new DatePicker('.demo_dashboard', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_dashboard' });
    new DatePicker('.demo_jqui', { pickerClass: 'datepicker_jqui', positionOffset: { x: 0, y: 5 } });
    new DatePicker('.demo', { positionOffset: { x: 0, y: 5 }});
});    
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

anyone have idea what is wrong with my code, please help

thank you

Comment: *"but still not working"* - What happens when you run it? Do you get any errors in the browser's console? (And why do you have script, link, and style elements *before* the head element?)

Comment: thx for replying. No there is no errors diplayed in browser or console
any idea?

Comment: "And why do you have script, link, and style elements before the head element?" i don't know, i just follow other site. i still newbie in this field. Then how it suppose to be?

Comment: If the site you are learning from does it the way you've shown then they're setting a bad example and I'd suggest you find a different tutorial site. See eeXBee's answer for how to include those elements in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You're not including your assets.
You have to put your links, stylesheets and js files inside the head tag.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker_jqui.css">        
    <style type="text/css">     
        input.date {
            width: 150px;
            color: #000;
        }
    </style>    
</head>
```

Comment: thank for your kind answer. But how to make that datepicker work?
i still figure it out, please help. thanks